# Refreshing a listview after changes

Tags: android, listview

I have written an activity which contains a `listview` and a FAB. My problem is I am feeding a new set of row with the help of FAB, which takes me to another activity, but after entering the new row to the `listView`, the `listView` doesn't refresh. I need to close the app and restart it to see the changes, but I don't know where to use the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Where I passed the value to the list and also I am specifying the whole class where I have written the adapter class.

```
public class ListDataAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListDataAdapter1(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    static class LayoutHandler {
        TextView ID, TYPE, AREA, LVLOE;
    }

    public void add(Object object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        LayoutHandler layoutHandler;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout1,parent,false);
            layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
            layoutHandler.ID = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.id);
            layoutHandler.TYPE = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.type);
            layoutHandler.AREA = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.area);
            layoutHandler.LVLOE = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.lvlofe);
            row.setTag(layoutHandler);
        }
        else
        {
            layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();
        }

        DataProvider1 dataProvider1 = (DataProvider1) this.getItem(position);
        layoutHandler.ID.setText(dataProvider1.getId1());
        Log.e(dataProvider1.getId1(), "Name of the value passed");
        layoutHandler.TYPE.setText(dataProvider1.getType1());
        layoutHandler.AREA.setText(dataProvider1.getArea1());
        layoutHandler.LVLOE.setText(dataProvider1.getLvloe1());

        return row;
    }
}

public class Addnew extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText ID,AREA,LVLOE;
String id,type,area,lvloe;
Button b1;
Context ctx=this;
Spinner SPINNER;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_new);
    setTitle("Add new entry ");
    ID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtid);
    SPINNER = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spntype);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.type_animals,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    SPINNER.setAdapter(adapter);
    SPINNER.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            type = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
    AREA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtarea);
    LVLOE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtlvlofe);
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.adden);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            id = ID.getText().toString();

            area = AREA.getText().toString();
            lvloe = LVLOE.getText().toString();
            DbOp db = new DbOp(ctx);
            db.putInformation1(db, id, type, area, lvloe);


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sucessfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();

        }
    });

}
```

}

```
public class DataProvider1 {
private String id1;
private String type1;
private String area1;
private String lvloe1;

public String getId1() {
    return id1;
}

public void setId1(String id1) {
    this.id1 = id1;
}

public String getType1() {
    return type1;
}

public void setType1(String type1) {
    this.type1 = type1;
}

public String getLvloe1() {
    return lvloe1;
}

public void setLvloe1(String lvloe1) {
    this.lvloe1 = lvloe1;
}

public String getArea1() {
    return area1;
}

public void setArea1(String area1) {
    this.area1 = area1;
}

public DataProvider1(String id1,String type1,String area1,String lvloe1 )
{
    this.id1 = id1;
    this.type1 = type1;
    this.area1 = area1;
    this.lvloe1 = lvloe1;

}
```

}

ListView listView;
    EditText view;

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
DbOp dbOp;
Cursor cursor;
ListDataAdapter1 listDataAdapter1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_activity);
    setTitle("Home ");

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listDataAdapter1 = new ListDataAdapter1(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter1);
    dbOp = new DbOp(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = dbOp.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = dbOp.getInformation1(sqLiteDatabase);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            String id,type,area,lvlofe;
            id = cursor.getString(0);
            type = cursor.getString(1);
            area = cursor.getString(2);
            lvlofe = cursor.getString(3);
            DataProvider1 dataProvider1 = new DataProvider1(id,type,area,lvlofe);
            listDataAdapter1.add(dataProvider1);



        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }


  }
public void addnew(View view)
{
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,Addnew.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.update:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,UpdateActivity1.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


        case R.id.delete:
            Intent intent= new Intent(this,DeleteEntry_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


        /*case R.id.logout:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent1);*/
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Use `notifyDataSetChanged` here:

```
public void add(Object object){
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Change your `onClick` method too:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        id = ID.getText().toString();

        area = AREA.getText().toString();
        lvloe = LVLOE.getText().toString();
        DbOp db = new DbOp(ctx);
        adapter.add(id+" "+area+" "+lvloe);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        db.putInformation1(db, id, type, area, lvloe);


        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sucessfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        finish();

    }
```

Comment: did that but no use,still its not refreshing :(

Comment: is there other methods other than "add" that you make changes to your "list" variable?

Comment: i added addnew class code in the original post which is responsible to open when i click on button present in the topmost class to add a new entry in the list,no other methods are present other than these which can make change in my list

Comment: yes yes exaclty,sorry for not clearing the point its my first post actually

Comment: can you also post DataProvider1 class contents?

Comment: @Dc_07 check the update and let me know if it fixed the problem

Comment: DataProvider1 provider = new DataProvider1(id, type, area, lvloe);
                adapter.add(provider);

in the second line error appears ,provider is not acceptable

Comment: ok wait i typecasted it and wrote but my app crashes when i add new row

Comment: you typecasted what exactly?

Comment: adapter.add((CharSequence) provider);




This

Comment: @Dc_07 check the updated answer, I changed couple of lines

Comment: @Dc_07 have you used ListDataAdapter1 anywhere?

Comment: i tried the updated code but app crashes again,yes i updated the post pls look at it

Comment: @Dc_07 I can't find the usage of ListDataAdapter1 in your code

Comment: @Dc_07 the app crashes with your updated code or just don't get updated?

Comment: when you came back from AddNew activity to previous activity, your onresume method call,  not oncreate method due to this new data is not added and listview is not updated

Comment: @pooya it crashes when i select add entry,so m unable to check that

Comment: @Ashim kansal so what should i do?pls guide

Answer (score -1):

use this code in onresume method of your activity

```
dbOp = new DbOp(getApplicationContext());
sqLiteDatabase = dbOp.getReadableDatabase();
cursor = dbOp.getInformation1(sqLiteDatabase);
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
    do{
        String id,type,area,lvlofe;
        id = cursor.getString(0);
        type = cursor.getString(1);
        area = cursor.getString(2);
        lvlofe = cursor.getString(3);
        DataProvider1 dataProvider1 = new     DataProvider1(id,type,area,lvlofe);
        if(listDataAdapter1!=null){
        listDataAdapter1.add(dataProvider1);
 }else{
        listDataAdapter1 = new      ListDataAdapter1(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
listView.setAdapter(listDataAdapter1);
}


    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

and call notifyDataSetChange() in add function in adapter class